# Choosing random words from a list according to previous variable

Tags: python

So, I'm making a python hangman for a class and I need to ask people which category of words to use and from that word create an array of empty spaces the length of the word which gets filled with the letter the user inputs, if it's there of course. I'm pretty stumped, I feel it's easy but right now I'm stuck.

```js
__author__ = 'rodrigocano'
import random
intentos = 0
incorrectos = 0
palabras_1 = ["disclosure","thenational","foals","skepta","shamir","kanye","fidlar","lcdsoundsystem",
              "lorde","fkatwigs","miguel","rtj","boniver","strokes"]
palabras_2 = ["vaporwave","witchouse","shoegaze","memerap","paulblartisoursaviour"]
palabras_3 = ["glockenspiel","aesthetic","schadenfreude","bonvivant","swag"]
eleccion = int
palabra = str
Array_Palabra = []

def Elegir_Categoria():
    eleccion = input("Bienvenido, que categoria quiere usar:"
                     '\n'"1 - Musica que Escuche Mientras Lo Hacia"
                     '\n'"2 - Generos Musicales"
                     '\n'"3 - Palabras Pretenciosas")
    return eleccion
Elegir_Categoria()

def Elegir_Palabra(eleccion):
    if eleccion == 1:
        palabra = random.choice(palabras_1)
    elif eleccion == 2:
        palabra = random.choice(palabras_2)
    elif eleccion == 3:
        palabra = random.choice(palabras_3)
    else:
        print("No es valido, por favor escoger nuevamente")
        Elegir_Categoria()
    return palabra

Elegir_Palabra(eleccion)

def Array_Palabra(palabra):
    for palabra in range (0, len(palabra)+1):
        Array_palabra = Array_Palabra.append("_")
    return Array_Palabra
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

Python `input` is always `string`. You need to explicitly convert it to int

```
(int(input(...))
```

Also name of a method and variable cannot be same,

```
 def Array_Palabra(palabra):
```

cannot be the same as

```
Array_Palabra = []
```

**EDIT:**
`Elegir_Palabra(eleccion)` returns `palabra` but you are not assigning the return value to any variable.
Replace with `variable_name = Elegir_Palabra(eleccion)`

Comment: Nope, didn't help. Still not letting me transfer the value from eleccion to the following function

Comment: @RodrigoCano Check edit. I haven't actually looked at your code in details. Those were the errors I spotted easily

Answer (score 0):

`input()` in Python 3 always returns a string. So you either need to convert the result to an integer (`return int(eleccion)`) or compare the result to string literals (`if eleccion == '1'`).

Besides:

Your code lines

```
 eleccion = int
 palabra = str
```

don't do anything useful. You cannot declare the type of a variable in Python. These just assign the type objects for int and str to the variables.